# Shorest-Seek-Time in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

So currently I'm working on a problem of implementing the shortest-seek-time disk scheduling algorithm. Our task is, being passed a list of tracks, to return a list of length 3 containing the Avg Movement, Total movement, and then a list of the movement amounts. Currently I'm tackling returning the list of movements as I feel the total and avg's are trivial.

What I'm currently stuck on is saving the distance between the current head position and the current track so I can continue searching the list for the shortest seek time. What I did first was to sort the list and pass it into a separate helper function that only returns the the shortest-movement from the current head position so I can continually call this function.

Is the best way to do this to simply pass in another variable to hold the distance and keep checking based on this number? and then remove that disk from the list once I've satisfied the movement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Scheme having accumulators and state as extra parameters to a helper function and update using recursion to have state during the execution without actually mutating bindings.

The simplest example:

```
(define (reverse lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (acc '()))
    (if (null? lst)
        acc
        (loop (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) acc)))))

(reverse '(1 2 3)) ; ==> (3 2 1)
```

**EDIT**

Now since you said you're not used to named `let` here is the same with a helper procedure and keeping the same names:

```
(define (reverse lst)
  ;; a helper with an accumulator
  (define (loop lst acc)
    (if (null? lst)
        acc
        (loop (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) acc))))
  ;; call the helper
  (loop lst '()))
```

Now the names `loop`, `lst`, `acc` are just variable names. However their names suggest `loop` is a tail recursive procedure. `lst` is a list and `acc` is short for accumulator which indicates on the base case it will be part of the result and for the default case it will be updated.

Comment: I've seen this done before but the line that always confuses me is (let loop ((lst lst) (acc '())), I don't understand what the (1st 1st) is doing, as well I don't believe I've seen acc before.

Comment: @nwelch `(let n ((a b) (c d)) ... (n x y)...)` is a "named let" which defines two variables , `a` which starts as `b` (as it exists just before this `let` is entered), and `c` which starts as `d` (as it exists just before this `let` is entered). When `(n x y)` is called inside its body, the `let` is re-entered with new `a` being assigned the value of `x`, and new `c` assigned the value of `y`. If this call to `(n x y)` was in tail position, this will describe a loop (so, it is customary to use `loop` instead of `n`) -- the "new" values will actually just replace the old ones.

Comment: @nwelch I've added a local procedure version.